# Static block in magento doesn't update

Tags: magento, static-block

I'm a complete newbie to magento so it's probably a silly question.
I have updated some code in a static block and saved it but the changes I've made aren't reflected on the website after refreshing the page?
Is there anything else I need to do to get those changes live?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: didn't realise there was one for magento, so thanks for the tip

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps.

1. Clear magento cache.
2. Make sure you are updating the correct static block. because
   sometimes there may be multiple static block with same identifiers.
3. Check store view configuration in edit static block section.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

It will take 1-2 hours before you can see the change online when editing a static block.